# How to get `command-not-found` working on Debian Stretch

Tags: debian, command-not-found

I have set up two Debian Stretch systems, one new installation by 'netinst' CD, one upgraded from Jessie.

After that, I have installed the *command-not-found* package.

```
apt install command-not-found
```

The installation ran smoothly, with neither errors nor warnings. As suggested in the installation process output, I ran `update-command-not-found` subsequently. This command does not give any output at all and returns with exit code 0 - no errors.

However, when I type some non-existing command, I get an error nevertheless:

> Could not find the database of available applications, run update-command-not-found as root to fix this
>   foobarbaz: command not found

This happens on both systems. I have no clue how to fix this issue. What have I missed?

---

**UPDATE:**
For some reason `update-command-not-found` worked on my local system just now. It shows some download URLs fetching data from. Now, the console works as expected. I did nothing since this morning, the system had gone in sleep mode while I was absent.

On the remote system the issue is remaining.

Answer (score 11):

The solution:

There were wrong entries in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. The package needs to be updated via the update repository. There has been a wrong entry derived from the provider's local Jessie mirror repository. I have changed the URLs to the original Stretch reporitory but missed to replace a slash by a dash (`stretch/updates` => `stretch-updates`).

Add to file `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
# stretch-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free
```

Run:

```
apt update
update-command-not-found
```

Comment: The interesting thing is: You can spend hours or days without finding an answer. Just after posting a question you get the sudden inspiration. :)

Comment: Actually, it was the apt update command that did the trick. Editing the sources.list was likely incorrect.

Comment: Indeed the apt update was the important key step I was missing.  It's funny, I run that almost religiously every few days, but I didn't think to do it after installing command-not-found until I read this.  It would be nice if the little helper message that says "run update-command-not-found" also mentioned updating your apt repos... or perhaps the update-cnf command just did it for you...

Comment: @NonnyMoose Actually there had been remaining incorrect entries in the sources.list. I routinely updated the repositories every time before changing any package installation. The differences between the local network mirror storage and public repositories caused the error in that case.

Comment: Asked for sudo here, `sudo apt-file update; sudo update-command-not-found`

Comment: @Wellington1993 I presuppose root privileges as I am the server admin. Actually there had been some local net mirror issue.