# Spell-checker for an interactive bash on Debian as Ubuntu?

Tags: bash, debian, ubuntu, spell-checking

I'm not sure, but I remember Ubuntu can do similar to:

```
$ miswrite-command

No 'miswrite-command' found, did you mean: 

 'correct-command' from 'correct-package' (main)

Try : sudo apt install correct-package
```

What is the package name to do such things on Debian?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement package install suggestion on Debian?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67466/how-to-implement-package-install-suggestion-on-debian) or [How to get `command-not-found` work on Debian Stretch](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381293/how-to-get-command-not-found-work-on-debian-stretch)

Comment: @Olorin Thank you, but this one half slolution, I'm not sure, but I remember Ubuntu can do spell-check when I use error package name in apt.

Comment: I don't know about that. I just tried `sudo apt install bsah` in Ubuntu and it said `E: Unable to locate package bsah` with no suggestions. `aptitude` might provide suggestions, in which case you can install `aptitude` in Debian just like you installed it in Ubuntu.

Comment: It's not exactly what you're asking for, but it might help: https://github.com/nvbn/thefuck

Comment: @Olorin I think the question is different. How make debian bash act like ubuntu e,g: fixing typos , giving suggestions and how to install the correct package.

Comment: @GAD3R thank you for edit and  I'm sorry for my bad, I edit my question to remove words about "apt package name spell check" because I think "spell check for bash command" and "spell check for apt package name" is a different thing.[See my first version](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/505050/1)

Comment: @GAD3R in either case it's a matter of correctly installing and configuring `command-not-found` like in the dupes.